# nvd3.js How to disable tooltips for one serie only

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm trying to disable the tooltip for the `line` serie of my chart and leave the one of the `bar` serie. I can't really see how I can do it.

The problem I have with both series' tooltips enabled is that I cannot see the tooltip of the `bar` serie because it's always selecting the one from the `line` which is closer. Maybe it's possible to trigger the tooltip if the mouse is closer to the point? at the moment it's triggering it at around 10-20px away from the point.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var chart = nv.models.linePlusBarChart()
    .margin({top: 30, right: 60, bottom: 50, left: 70})
    ...
  ;

chart.lines.interactive(false) // add this line
```

Comment: Thanks mate, now I have to find how to do this with [angularjs-nvd3-directives](https://github.com/cmaurer/angularjs-nvd3-directives/issues/195) :(

Comment: I've submitted a [Pull Request](https://github.com/cmaurer/angularjs-nvd3-directives/pull/199) to the project. Thanks again fro your help!

Comment: YMW...glad to have been of help.